# Dynamically Creating K8s (AKS) Namespaces for Every Branch/Pull Request in GitLab via jenkins

Tags: azure-aks

We have environment with Azure Kubernetes + Jenkins + GitLab.
 With existing setup once after merge request on GitLab, build is triggered in Jenkins and pods are deployed on Azure K8s (AKS). Now we have the requirement to have dynamic namespace for all pull request and uris to be tested for each branch. Later once it's merged we have to delete those dynamic namespace.
Could you kindly guide me with setup or approach to get this achieved.

Comment: `kubectl create namespace` is not enough for you?

Comment: No, I'm not looking for just the namespace.  Looking ephemeral kubernetes environment for every pull request. While checking on the Codefresh , harniess  will help me here. Correct me if I'm wrong . 
If this could help me , which is best for AKS, jenkins and GitLab environment

Comment: now you're messing up concepts of environments and namespaces in k8s. It's better to describe what exactly you'd like to achieve with "dynamic namespaces" - isolation from other resources? Volatility? Something else?

Comment: To refine,  requirement is to have pod deployed for every pull request and should have the URI for each  and should  be deleted post Merge request is submitted.

So i thought to have dynamic namespace based on each pull request with the pod deployed and ingress configured to have specific URL without disturbing the existing QA domain URL and this is could be shared for development team.

Post verification and once they plan for merge request, entire namespace has to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kubectl is your way to go. You just need to create a namespace and/or deployment with a unique hash (which you can extract from git commit hash for the PR):

```
kubectl create namespace NAMESPACE_NAME_COMMIT_HASH
```

I'm pretty sure you can cover all your requirements with a single testing namespace just by generating deployments+service+ingress with a unique commit hash in their names and deleting them in the end of pipeline. There will be no collision in the testing namespace unless your pods do not initiate some sort of intra-namespace communication between them, e.g. clustering etc.

Comment: To do with "deployments+service+ingress" with unique namespace.
For ingress step,  do you mean to create a new ingress controller and ingress file each time ?

Comment: you just need to create "Ingress" Object each time with a unique name in your unique namespace pointing to your unique service